# JavaScript Custom Tracker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to build a tracking system for a Web-based Application built in CakePHP 2.x. The idea is to have all the tracked link having written as below:

```
<a 
  href="#" 
  class="track-click" 
  data-tracking='{ 
    "trackers": [
      {
        "tracker": "----", 
        "eventId": "---",
        "tracking_options": { 
          "eventTargetUrl": "---", 
          "props": [{ 
            "key": "----", 
            "value": "---"  
          }]
        } 
      } 
    ]
  }'
/>
```

The javascript that handles the track requests should be able to gather the information that resides inside the data-tracking attribute. This would be done by  attaching a click event on the "track-click" class onClick event.

Below is how I use the link above:

```
$('.track-click').click(function(e){
  //Lets grab the data thats within the data-tracking attribute and do something with it
  var data = $(this).attr('data-tracking');
  alert(data.trackers);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

At this present moment if I alert the above I get undefined. If I put $(this).attr('data-tracking').val() on my code I get the error below:

```
TypeError: $(...).attr(...).val is not a function
```

What is the best way of manipulating links that have a json data as shown above?

Comment: Did you try closing in HTML the last attribute (data-tracking) with single quote, ' ? It seems not to be closed.

Comment: Close your a tag and put single quote at the end of this string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
var data = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-tracking'));
```

This will return you the object.

Else you must use

```
  var data = $(this).data('tracking');
```

.data() will return you the object. whereas .attr() will stringify and return that object.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sitilifutu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

Comment: Thanks dude this is exactly what I wanted. I could see [object Object] being alerted i my browser which is a good sign.... :-)

Comment: Great. you can console.log and see the entire object in console :)

Comment: Yes, I wqas able to see the whole data rather than the [object Object] notation with the alert. Thanks a lot. I am now trying to build the implementation for my custom tracking... :-)